# Confusing about storing data in array

Tags: java, fibonacci

hi guys i have a problem for my program i do a program that user will input a fibonacci digits and the answer will be "Yes" if it's fibonacci digits and "No" if no. this is my code so far .

sample:
input
1
3
5
7

output
Yes
Yes
Yes
No

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Storage
{
    public static void main(String args [])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        int a,b,c;
        b =0;
        c =1;
        boolean vince = false;

        int []stor = new int[10];
        for(int v=0; v<stor.length; v++)
        {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a+b;
            stor[v] = c;

        }


        System.out.println("Input");

        String [] stor2 = new String[10];
        for(int v=0; v<stor.length; v++)
        {


            int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            for(int k=0; k<stor2.length; k++)
            {
                if(stor[k] == x)
                {
                    vince = true;

                    if(vince)
                    {
                        stor2[k] = "Yes";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stor2[k] = "No";
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for(int p=0; p<stor2.length; p++)
        {
            System.out.print(stor2[p]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my problem is When i inputted a not fibonacci number it's only display Null. i want it to be "NO"

Comment: Did you use your debugger and step through the program in order to figure out why this could be happening?

Comment: no sir. i am using notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize all of the elements of `stor2` to be `"No"`, so that every one not explicitly assigned `"Yes"` will print out as `"No"`; as currently written, those elements not explicitly assigned to in your loop will be be `Null`, and printed as such.

Comment: `for (k=0; k<stor2.length; k++ ) stor2[k] = "No";`

Comment: I don't agree with this, please see the `if (vince)` portion of the code. The OP initializes with either "Yes" or "No".

Comment: so i will remove my "Yes" to my condition?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi i am having an runtime error when my "Yes" or "No" is in the first condition

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Only if `story[k]==x`; otherwise, it is left as `Null`.

Comment: @shampoo: Add the loop I put in the comment right after you declare `stor2`; do *not* remove your `Yes` condition (although the `else` assigning `"No"` can be removed, since it will already be `"No"`).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: That's why I get the big bucks :)

Comment: And a sad life. Don't worry, I do production support as well, fixing someone else's code. You don't have to lie to us! :D

Comment: :OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 0):

Hey look what is the problem...

Your code:

```
         vince = true;

                if(vince==true)
                {
                   System.out.println("Entered yes");
                    stor2[k] = "Yes";
                }
                else if(vince==false)
                {
                     System.out.println("Entered no");
                    stor2[k] = "No";
                }
```

Your code never enter to the second else cause the **vince** goes never **false**

One **solution** is:

boolean vince = false;

```
  System.out.println("Input");

    String [] stor2 = new String[10];
     for(int p=0; p<stor2.length; p++) //Here make all "No" before begin
        stor2[p]="No";


    for(int v=0; v<stor.length; v++)
    {.....}
```

Run this....

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
 public class Storage
{
   public static void main(String args [])throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    int a,b,c;
    b =0;
    c =1;
    boolean vince = false;

    int []stor = new int[10];
    for(int v=0; v<stor.length; v++)
    {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a+b;
        stor[v] = c;

    }


    System.out.println("Input");

    String [] stor2 = new String[10];

    for(int p=0; p<stor2.length; p++)
       stor2[p]="No";



    for(int v=0; v<stor.length; v++)
    {


        int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        for(int k=0; k<stor2.length; k++)
        {
            if(stor[k] == x)
            {
                vince = true;

                if(vince==true)
                {
                   System.out.println("Entered yes");
                    stor2[k] = "Yes";
                }
                else if(vince==false)
                {
                     System.out.println("Entered no");
                    stor2[k] = "No";
                }
            }
        }

    }


     for(int p=stor2.length-1; p>=0; p--)
    {
        System.out.print(stor2[p]);
    }

  }
  }
```

Let me know if it works i simple filled the  array with "NO" and print 
from the end to begin.

Comment: the output is always said no no no no no no even though i entered fibonacci numbers

Comment: when i run this peace of code for(1,2,4,6,7) it prints Yes Yes null null  null  and what you except to print when the other elements of store2[] are null?

Comment: here's i want it to be .

Inputted value :7 1 2 3 5

Output :NO, Yes ,Yes ,Yes ,Yes . because 7 is not a fibonacci sequence

Comment: i run your code. i input 7 at first but YES is the output below

Comment: my first input 7,1 . Output NO NO . 1 is fibonacci :3

Comment: Check your code if it find the fibonnachi right...(that's all for tonight )

Comment: i answered your question and now the code dont print [null] that you asked... you find the way for your code.